# value create is not a member of object org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient

Tags: scala

I am trying to use `KafkaAdminClient.create` in Scala as the following:

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient


final class DetectorActor extends TemplateActor {

  val props = new Properties
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  props.put("connections.max.idle.ms", "10000")
  props.put("request.timeout.ms", "5000")

  val adminClient = {
    val client = KafkaAdminClient.create(props)

  }

  override def receive: Receive = ???
}
```

and it does not work, because the `Scala` compiler can not find `KafkaAdminClient.create(props)` factory method.

```
value create is not a member of object org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient
[error]     val client = KafkaAdminClient.create(props)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient` extends `org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient`.

It's the latter that has static method `create(props: Properties): AdminClient`

```
val client = AdminClient.create(props)
```

Scaladoc for `KafkaAdminClient` says

```
/**
 * The default implementation of {@link AdminClient}. 
 * An instance of this class is created by invoking one of the
 * {@code create()} methods in {@code AdminClient}. 
 * Users should not refer to this class directly.
```

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient